# What's the point of paintings?

Tags: elden-ring

I have collected a number of paintings across the world, but they don't seem to serve any obvious purpose other than sitting in my inventory. Aside from [simply being "This is art, stare at the art"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw_HozTyCvI), what is the purpose of paintings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paintings show places of the game. If you go to these places, you'll see a ghost NPC. Talk to this ghost and it will give you a reward and disappear.

---

Sources about where to find the paintings, the ghosts and the rewards: [the Fextralife wiki](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Info+Items) or [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/elden-ring/Painting_Locations_and_Solutions#Paintings_in_Elden_Ring).

Comment: Good start, but can you add sources? Also the locations? I also read that there is an award for finding them all.

Comment: @TimmyJim I added sources, but I can't find anything about an award for finding them all.

Comment: Nevermind. I *thought* I read that but I was wrong.

Comment: Note: not places depicted in the painting (which are often sprawling landscapes) but the specific locations the paintings were painted from. Often quite hard to access, e.g. the "Redmane" painting depicting the field where you fight Radahn and distant Redmane castle was made from a ledge accessible by a series of very precarious drops from near Lenne's Rise, and guarded by a particularly powerful golem, really hard to fight in the limited space (you can access it without waking the golem, but it's dangerously close).